# Working on same database from 2 diffent pc's

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, vps

I had a Question about working on the same MySQL database. If I am in college I am always working on my laptop. But if I get home than I rather use my PC for coding. 
But I don't wanna import and export my database always. I just wanna connect to a server or something so I can work from both.

Is there any way to do that with a VPS or something? I don't mind to make one with Linux or windows but what is the easiest way to work from 2 different devices and what do I need to do to make that happen.

Comment: setting up mysql for remote access is trivial and covered in at least 39384848392920 tutorials. Use google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install MySQL on your laptop.
Copy/move the database onto it.  Use the laptop as your server when you get home.

If you don't want your laptop on all the time, use a cheap web host to share it over the t'interwebs.

If you like, look at AWS free tier.  Finally, Zapier do a MySQL & OneDrive collaboration that could do what you want.